# disable hyperlink in calendar event view, but keep the 'expand' option available

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

have a javascript code that will stop the links, but will also stop the links to 'expand' if more that 3 items exist.  is there a way using javascript to only stop the event hyperlink?

thanks in advance.

link to disable hyperlink:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3492bb87-ed0d-4fa6-9f40-1473a964bcc1/how-to-remove-displayform-link-from-items-in-a-calendar-view-spo?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: thank you sooooo much, this works great, saves me so much time, the links disable but for some reason it doesn't expand by default.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85175)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {      
     setInterval(function (){
        $(".ms-acal-item").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });
        $(".ms-acal-item a").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });

        $(".ms-acal-item a").each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });     
    },1000);
});
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, works fantastic, except for the expand function, still stays a collapsed by default.