# Disabling links within a Calendar View

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, calendar-view

I am using SharePoint 2013 OP.

I have a calendar view, with several re-occuring appointments. Is there a way of disabling the link, so that you can't click into the appointment to see further details?

Thanks

Comment: You need to disable links on whole calender view or only for that several appointments?

Comment: For that entire calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script I tested and worked in my end. Please have a try. It is from the thread here: [disable hyperlink in calendar event view, but keep the 'expand' option available](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/232923/disable-hyperlink-in-calendar-event-view-but-keep-the-expand-option-available)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {      
     setInterval(function (){
        $(".ms-acal-item").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });
        $(".ms-acal-item a").bind("click dblclick", function () {
            return false;
        });

        $(".ms-acal-item a").each(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });     
    },1000);
});
</script>
```